# Git Bash confusion with mv command when I have same folder name and filename

Tags: git, bash

In Git Bash mv command moves or renames file or folder. What if I have in same folder mylabel.txt as folder . I can type mv somefilename.txt mylabel.txt and it will move somefilename.txt to folder mylabel.txt. What if I wanted to rename file somefilename.txt to mylabel.txt? Can someone explain this weird situation?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have, in one directory, a file and a directory with the same name.

Comment: If it's just an empty folder created by mistake; do something like *rmdir folder; git mv ...*.